# Flashing LPC1768 with OpenOCD

Tags: jtag, openocd, lpc1768

I'm venturing into JTAG flashing, and thought OpenOCD would be a good place to start. I had a quick look through the documentation and found it hideously complicated. Likewise, the very few "tutorials" I found on other websites were either incomplete, hard to follow, or relating to other hardware.

From start to finish, how would I go about flashing a basic LED blinky program onto the LPC1768 via JTAG, using OpenOCD?

Comment: First, you need a debugger/programmer.

Comment: This question is too broad to fit the format of this site - you are **requesting a custom tutorial** or for other people to do the web searches to find an existing one, neither of which are within the stack exchange mission of specific narrow questions only.